# Searching a List of Strings (100 000 Strings): How to search for x character if there is a %

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist

I am programming an android app in Java and I need to show a `ListView`.

But before creating the `ListView` I need to fill my `Adapter` with data.
I have a `ArrayList` of String and I want to search that `ArrayList` by an `EditText`.

My `Arraylist` has 100 000+ entries.

- I want to get ABC from `ArrayList` when typing ABC.
- I want to get ABC, AAC, ACC, ADC, ... from `ArrayList` when typing A_C so in this case the _  needs to replace a character. It also should work for multiple underlines next to each other and not next to each other.
- I want to get ABC, AAC, ACC, ADC, ABAC, ABBC,... from `ArrayList` when typing A%C so in this case the % needs to replace multiple characters. It also should work for multiple % not next to each other. This is I think the same thing like the star * in windows.

Hope you could help.

Comment: What are the errors/issues you are facing currently? ... and where is your code?

Comment: This is absolutely crazy. You should use a database for such a high amount of data.

Comment: RegEx is the way to go. Check if the input contains a _ or % and go for a RegEx filter instead of a simple text filter.

Comment: Thanks @KlingKlang but my app is for the local network / intranet.

Comment: @Korashen and then loop over all strings and check for a match?

Comment: ... aaaaaand? what prevents you from using a remote database?

Comment: @DanijelMarinkovic that does not matter, databases do not need to be online, but they normally come with proper text indexing built-in, which is what you need.

Comment: So it is possible with RegEx? A database would be the last thing my boss wants, because I need to download a csv from our file server, which is being replaced every 5 days. Nobody would be able to update this stuff in the database.

Comment: `A database would be the last thing my boss wants,` So he doesn't care for performance `because I need to download a csv from our file server,` This is absolutely crazy. With a database, you don't need to download anythyng. Simply query the db with an appropriate filter criterion and get the results in no time.

Comment: @KlingKlang I know, I know. Thank you for your feedback. But yes, however, I need to get a solution with RegEx.

Comment: Can we please stop the discussions about a database or not? We are not the customers. We do not place the requirements. We can give the hint to use a database and fine. If the customer does not want it, that's it. Do it the way the customer wants it.

Comment: The regex itself is very basic, just escape and character in the input that has a regex meaning. Then replace `%` with `.*` and `_` with `.`. Then loop over the strings and apply the regex, expect quite the delay until you get a result.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, Use a parallel Stream to search through all the strings. That is how I would do it, with the given information.

Comment: @luk2302 but how to search the `ArrayList` by regex? Really nice of to for the help.

Comment: Anyway, the query for a database (in case your boss becomes more reasonable) looks like `SELECT ColumnList FROM YourTable WHERE ASpecificColumn LIKE 'A%C'`. Isn't that EASY, other than EFFICIENT?

Comment: E.g. `for (String str : list) { /* match?? */ }`, as I said already that will potentially take a while...

Comment: Thanks to @KlingKlang!
And big thnx to @luk2302 I will try to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A serious **non answer**: consider not doing this within your app.

When you are dealing with such enormous amounts of data, you really don't want that processing happening on (potentially cheap) mobile phone hardware. Sooner or later, some people will use your app on inadequate hardware, and then they will complain about "the app is super slow".

Meaning: consider doing this in some sort of *backend* service. And then, use a technology *built* for dealing with large amounts of text data, such as [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). So, yes, the app might send strings to your service, as you type, and the service sends back suggestions, lists, whatever.

Comment: Really thankful for you answer, but I cannot make a backend service I must do this in my app. Btw. the app is for internal usage, no clients.

Comment: @DanijelMarinkovic Internal customers can be worse. They can talk to their manager, who then talks to your manager. That is the thing: the more **valuable** your app will be to other people, the more they depend on it. The more you will get grilled when it is not working (perfectly).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. First, we are creating a regular expression that matches your search term, then we filter the list using `paralellStream()` as recommended by Korashen.

The regex `(?<=[_%])|(?=[_%])` will split the String at `_` and `%` while preserving the delimiters. For example, if you split `"A_B"` the result would be `["A","_","B"]` and not `["A","B"]`.

```
private static List<String> filterByTerm(List<String> list, String term) {
    StringBuilder regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] array = term.split("(?<=[_%])|(?=[_%])");
    for(String s : array) {
        switch(s) {
        case "_":
            regexBuilder.append(".");
            break;
        case "%":
            regexBuilder.append(".*");
            break;
        default:
            regexBuilder.append(Pattern.quote(s));
        }
    }

    String regex = regexBuilder.toString();
    return list.parallelStream().filter(s -> s.matches(regex)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Minimal verified example:**

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add("ABC");
input.add("AAC");
input.add("ACC");
input.add("ADC");

String term = "AB_";

filterByTerm(input, term).forEach(System.out::println);
```

gives the output of `ABC`.

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` of strings is not the right data structure for this task. The only way to search such a list is to iterate through all of them, which will be slow. You want a data structure which supports you with the kind of queries that you're doing. The cost of this will probably be an increased memory footprint.

A tree structure of characters seems like it would work well. You would represent the words AAB, ABA and ABB as the following tree:

```
     A
    / \
   A   B
  /   / \
 B   A   B
```

I also strongly agree with GhostCat that you probably don't want to do this client-side.

Below is a quick implementation. I make no guarantees that it works perfectly or optimally - it is a demonstration of what's possible, not production-ready code. I haven't tested it with large data sets.

It only supports your underscore rule, but it should be simple enough to adapt it to also support your multicharacter matching.

---

A generic interface which is implemented by both the root and actual char nodes, and contains the default search implementation:

```
interface CharTree
{
    List<CharNode> getChildren();

    default Optional<CharNode> getChild(char character)
    {
        return getChildren().stream()
            .filter(ch -> ch.getCharacter() == character)
            .findFirst();
    }

    default void search(final String pattern, final StringBuilder builder, final Set<String> results)
    {
        if (pattern.isEmpty())
        {
            results.add(builder.toString());
            return;
        }

        char character = pattern.toCharArray()[0];
        final List<CharNode> candidates;
        if (character == '_')
        {
            candidates = getChildren();
        }
        else
        {
            candidates = getChild(character)
                .map(Collections::singletonList)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
        }

        for (final CharNode node : candidates)
        {
            builder.append(node.getCharacter());
            node.search(pattern.substring(1, pattern.length()), builder, results);
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Basic root implementation, with a static method to build the tree:

```
class Root implements CharTree
{
    private Root() { }

    @Getter private List<CharNode> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Root buildTree(final List<String> words)
    {
        final Root root = new Root();
        for (final String word : words)
        {
            CharTree current = root;
            for (char character : word.toCharArray())
            {
                Optional<CharNode> node = current.getChild(character);
                if (node.isPresent())
                {
                    current = node.get();
                }
                else
                {
                    final CharNode tmp = new CharNode(character);
                    current.getChildren().add(tmp);
                    current = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Simple character node (annotations are from Lombok)

```
@Data
@ToString(of = "character")
class CharNode implements CharTree
{
    private final char character;
    private List<CharNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Some unit tests in case anyone cares:

```
@Test
public void one()
{
    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
    final CharTree root = Root.buildTree(words);

    final Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    root.search("aaa", new StringBuilder(), results);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, results.size());
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("aaa"));
}

@Test
public void two()
{
    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("aaa", "aba", "abb");
    final CharTree root = Root.buildTree(words);

    final Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    root.search("a_a", new StringBuilder(), results);

    Assert.assertEquals(2, results.size());
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("aaa"));
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("aba"));
}

@Test
public void three()
{
    final List<String> words = Arrays.asList("aaa", "aba", "abb");
    final CharTree root = Root.buildTree(words);

    final Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    root.search("___", new StringBuilder(), results);

    Assert.assertEquals(3, results.size());
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("aaa"));
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("aba"));
    Assert.assertTrue(results.contains("abb"));
}
```

Comment: Interesting tought, i really liked your idea to use a tree. Memory footprint should be a little bit bigger, but searching faster.